# Multiple Re-Write Conditions

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Is there a way I should be writing multiple re-write conditions for my domain? I want the I.P to forward to the domain name and all domain name variations forwarded to https. The domain can be found at https://www.getrideshare.com. I've included the snippet below in the .htaccess file.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^107\.180\.51\.9
 RewriteRule (.*) https://getrideshare.com/$1 [R=301,L]
 RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
 </IfModule>
 # END WordPress
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do your rule this way.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^107\.180\.51\.9 [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
 RewriteRule (.*) https://getrideshare.com/$1 [R=301,L]

 RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
 </IfModule>
```

Let me know how it works out.

Comment: Still no dice. I've tried writing it multiple ways and restarting Apache but I can't get the I.P to forward to the domain. Any other Ideas?

I do appreciate the effort, however.

Comment: That is the way you do it. Try and clear your browser cache and try another browser. That should work. Who is the ISP?

Comment: Actually I tried the IP and it doesn't show the site. So it seems as if this might be on shared hosting or something? It doesn't seem dedicated or VPS because the IP address should show the website and not a parked page.

Comment: We actually just purchased the economy go-daddy server option for this IP redirect, today. It was on shared hosting but we've moved the domain and website contents to what go daddy calls "a dedicated economy server" however based on the issues we are seeing I'm assuming we will still have the shared hosting issues as before.

Comment: It does appear that way. Godaddy, has very strange setups and is very hard to configure properly unfortunately. However it were normal dedicate IP to your server, the rules would work.

Comment: Thank you sir, I'll take it up with GoDaddy from here as I do believe it is written correctly!

Issue resolved.